# Use of commas versus "and" in lists

Tags: conjunctions

Which of these two sentences are grammatically correct?

1. I lost my bag and my book and my pen.
2. I lost my bag, book and pen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are fully grammatical. For me the most natural form would be

> I lost my bag, my book, and my pen.*

But both of your examples are fine.

*Note on punctuation: some people will object to the comma after 'book'. I have a definite preference for using it, the [Oxford comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma).